# Uploading Lottie animation files with images

Tags: field, image, json

For anyone who doesn't know what [Lottie](https://airbnb.design/lottie/) is, it is a video player created by the AirBnB team that lets you play vector animation exported from Adobe After Effects. It exports as json-files that you can easily add to any web project. This is easy to upload in craft cms or include in a static website. However sometimes I have images included in the animation that needs to be linked correctly in the json-file.

I was just wondering if anyone else have encountered this problem and found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

How are the images included in the json-file? Do you need upload the images as well? I assume, that you do have a problem with the image paths? Please describe your workflow and folder structure.

Frontend-Side you could always replace some strings via twig. In your case you could replace a path-segment from the json field.

Comment: Here is how I have solved it when there is no images 

    {% for json in block.json.all() %}

        <div id="{{ json.filename | lower }}"></div>

        <script>
        var animation = bodymovin.loadAnimation({
          container: document.getElementById('{{ json.filename | lower }}'),
          renderer: 'svg',
          loop: true,
          autoplay: true,

          path: '{{ json.getUrl() }}'

        })
        </script>
{% endfor %}

I just upload the json-file and link to it here. Also I use the filename to target the div above the script.

Comment: But when when there is images they actually need to be linked in the json-file so I guess uploading the file seperate from the twig file probably will not work? I need to add the json-data in the twig-file to be able to edit image paths.

Comment: could you upload an example json file?

Comment: When using lottiefiles.com I am able to upload a zip-file with the json-file and images to preview the animation. Uploading a zip like that in Craft CMS would be perfect if it was possible.

Anyways here you can see a demo json-file:
https://assets7.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_f1MCbZ/Lottie-2/demo.json

And here is a preview of how the animation looks:
https://lottiefiles.com/share/f1MCbZ